# Какой принцип действия функций в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Вопрос в JavaScripte, не могу понять принцип действия функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В простом варианте работает так:
Создаем функцию, которая выведет введенное нами сообщение на экран:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendMessageForm(){
     alert('Привет мир');
}
</script>
```

Затем мы хотим вызвать функцию по какому либо событию на странице сайта, например по нажатию кнопки. Делается это так:

```
<input type="button" id="send_message" onclick="sendMessageForm();">
```

По нажатию на кнопку сработает функция sendMessageForm и нам выведется сообщение "Привет мир".